# iOS8/Swift: Tab Bar Item getting smaller on click

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I just encountered a weird bug when giving insets to my Tab Bar images.

When I click the image in the built version, the image will apply the inset every time i click it -> so if you click it 3x it will basically disappear - if you click another Tab Bar Item it reappears again.

Obviously this only happens if you set left/right inset - not if you only set top/bottom

Anyone knows how to fix this without resizing the actual Tab Bar Image externally?

Comment: It would help if you posted some code. This smells like misplaced code.

Comment: there is no handwritten code involved - i set the tab bar items/controller/etc. in storyboard

Comment: you can also reproduce this in a new tab bar example project - just fill in the insets as said and you will see some weird animation/resize going on

Answer (score 52):

**Steps to resolve the issue:**

1. Select the tab bar item of the problematic ViewControllers in IB
2. Go to Size Inspector section (on the right)

Ensure your image insets are balanced
 If you give 5px inset to top then balance with a -5px inset to bottom
 If you give 5px inset to left then balance with a -5px inset to right

Comment: Funny, but it was exactly the reason why it happened in my project! I experimented with insets and forgot to clear them up. Thanks a lot!!